# Game Center achievements are rewarded every time

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I am adding achievements into an xCode project. The code below that I am using works fine in awarding the achievement but the only problem is that it is constantly being awarded in the background in the debug console. This is happening every time I load the game.

I also find that when the achievement is awarded for the very first time the completion banner is on repeat.

My question today is how do I edit the code to only award the achievement once, display the banner and then never appear again?

```
-(void)Scoring
{
    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + AddedScore;
    AddedScore = AddedScore - 1;

    if (AddedScore < 0) {
        AddedScore = 0;
    }

    Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", ScoreNumber];

    if (ScoreNumber > 110 && ScoreNumber < 1000) {
        LevelNUmber = 2;
        //self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        GKAchievement *achievement= [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"_level1easy"];
        achievement.percentComplete = 100.0;
        achievement.showsCompletionBanner = YES;
        if(achievement!= NULL)
            {
                NSArray *achievements = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:achievement, nil];
                [GKAchievement reportAchievements:achievements withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                    if (error != nil) {
                        NSLog(@"Error in reporting achievements: %@", error);
                    } else {
                        NSLog(@"Achievement 1 Success");
                        }
                }];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then you just need to save the state of your achievement somewhere, then check it when you go into your Scoring method. Maybe try saving in NSUserdefaults, for example;

```
NSUserDefaults *savedScoring = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[savedScoring setObject:self.showsCompletionBanner forKey:@"showsCompletionBanner"];
```

Then check this whenever you game loads.